# Java class instances

Tags: java, class, object, instance

what does instantiate two instances in java means?
is it the same with create two objects?

I'am sorry I'm just new to java and it's hard grasping the idea of object programming when you came from C.

Comment: Short answer: `MyClass myObject - new MyClass();`.  A "class" is basically a template; a definition.  An "object instance" occupies memory, and has state.  To "instantiate an instance" in Java means to "new" an object instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`instantiate two instances` is simple giving memory to two Objects.

In c it is equivalent to `malloc`

**example**

```
Object obj1;
Object obj2;

obj1 = new Object(); //instantiating object1
obj2 = new Object(); //instantiating object2
```

Answer (score 2):

Each time you instantiate a class you create an object. If you have two instances of a class you have two objects.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, instantiate two instances means creating two objects of the class.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer yes!
instances = objects

Check how Java define them in the following documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate basically means assigning memory to objects.

```
Object a; //Not instantiated
Object b = new Object(); //Instantiated
```